# How to correctly map Nepal in d3.js using Albers projections?

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, map-projections

I am trying to create an interactive map of Nepal in d3.js with a topojson file. I have been able to do so with the d3.geo.albers() projection. The code I used in given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.feature {
  fill: #ccc;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([86, 28])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([27, 32]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("data/nepal3.json", function(error, npl) {
    var districts = topojson.feature(npl, npl.objects.nepal_districts);

    projection
      .scale(1)
      .translate([0, 0]);

    var b = path.bounds(districts),
      s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][2]) / height),
      t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][3] + b[0][4])) / 2];

    projection
      .scale(s)
      .translate(t);

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(districts)
      .attr("class", "feature")
      .attr("d", path);   
});
```

The map I get is not quite what I want. It is projected the wrong way than how the standard map of nepal looks like.

It looks like [this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s14/sh/1673c44a-b230-4cd9-b63e-40a64756b7a7/84f836ecd3e206bec38c040b42e6c5d9/deep/0/localhost-8008.png), instead of the usual [projection](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/maps/asia/nepal/).

What am I doing wrong here? Are there any other projections more suitable for the co-ordinated of Nepal?

Comment: It looks like you've rotated the projection in the wrong direction, i.e. are looking at Nepal through the earth from the other side. Have you tried rotating 180 degrees?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yup, that actually worked :). Is there any literature out there on this kind of stuff? Also, if you put this in the answer I can accept it.

Comment: Well, there's lots and lots of literature on geographic projections and the like. I'll add the answer, thanks.

Comment: @sfactor can you share the full d3 file? I am interested in making one too.

Comment: @ChandanGupta I've not done much after this but you can download my code from the following location as a starting point. https://github.com/batuwa/nepal_d3_map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've rotated the projection in the wrong direction, i.e. are looking at Nepal through the earth from the other side. It should work fine if you rotate it by 180 degrees, i.e.

```
.rotate([184.4,0])
```